# Why is observed clock rate < 3MHz on Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno

I wrote a simple loop to test the processor speed on my Arduino Uno. The numbers I'm getting are much worse than the 16MHz advertised, by a factor of ~5. Trying to figure out what I'm missing.

```
long counter = 0;
int sum = 0;
uint32_t t = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  t = micros();
}

void loop() {
  sum += counter;

  if (counter == 10000) {
    float usecsPerIteration = (micros() - t) / (counter * 1.0);
    Serial.print(usecsPerIteration);
    Serial.println(" microseconds per iteration");

    // Print result to avoid loop getting optimized away
    Serial.println(sum);
  }

  ++counter;
}
```

The output is:

```
3.77 microseconds per iteration
```

Here's how I'm estimating clock rate from this. The body of the loop involves two additions and an equality check. Even if we assume that these simple operations take 10 clock cycles, the implied clock rate is still just (1 iter / 3.77 us) * (1e6 us / sec) * (10 cycles / iter) = 2.65 MHz.

What am I missing?

Comment: You forgot that the printing itself also contributes to the equation. This is VERY EXPENSIVE. You should reset your time after every printing.

Comment: I only print once after 10,000 iters and it is after I compute time elapsed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Michael says there is a lot more going on than you think.

Firstly there are interrupts triggering which can slow things down (used to calculate milllis()).

Secondly you vastly under estimate the number of instructions that are being called.  For a start the `loop` is being called from a `for(;;)` loop in `main()`:

```
    for (;;) {
        loop();
4   572:    0e 94 73 00     call    0xe6    ; 0xe6 <loop>
        if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
2   576:    20 97           sbiw    r28, 0x00   ; 0
2   578:    e1 f3           breq    .-8         ; 0x572 <main+0x10>
-   57a:    0e 94 1d 01     call    0x23a   ; 0x23a <_Z14serialEventRunv>
2   57e:    f9 cf           rjmp    .-14        ; 0x572 <main+0x10>
10 total
```

Then for the call to `loop()` the registers used get pushed to the stack, then your code executed, and the registers popped off again before returning.  This is the code for loop when disassembled:

```
000000e6 <loop>:
    // Save the registers to the stack
2   e6:     cf 92           push    r12
2   e8:     df 92           push    r13
2   ea:     ef 92           push    r14
2   ec:     ff 92           push    r15
8 total

    // Add to the sum
2   ee:     40 91 44 01     lds r20, 0x0144 ; 0x800144 <counter>
2   f2:     50 91 45 01     lds r21, 0x0145 ; 0x800145 <counter+0x1>
2   f6:     60 91 46 01     lds r22, 0x0146 ; 0x800146 <counter+0x2>
2   fa:     70 91 47 01     lds r23, 0x0147 ; 0x800147 <counter+0x3>
2   fe:     80 91 42 01     lds r24, 0x0142 ; 0x800142 <sum>
2   102:    90 91 43 01     lds r25, 0x0143 ; 0x800143 <sum+0x1>
1   106:    84 0f           add r24, r20
1   108:    95 1f           adc r25, r21
2   10a:    90 93 43 01     sts 0x0143, r25 ; 0x800143 <sum+0x1>
2   10e:    80 93 42 01     sts 0x0142, r24 ; 0x800142 <sum>
18 total

    // Check the value to see if it's time to print
1   112:    40 31           cpi r20, 0x10   ; 16
1   114:    57 42           sbci    r21, 0x27   ; 39
1   116:    61 05           cpc r22, r1
1   118:    71 05           cpc r23, r1
2   11a:    d1 f5           brne    .+116       ; 0x190 <loop+0xaa>
6 total

    // From here on is the "IF" section - skipped by the BRNE above
-   11c:    0e 94 f5 04     call    0x9ea   ; 0x9ea <micros>
-   120:    c0 90 3e 01     lds r12, 0x013E ; 0x80013e <__data_end>
-   124:    d0 90 3f 01     lds r13, 0x013F ; 0x80013f <__data_end+0x1>
-   128:    e0 90 40 01     lds r14, 0x0140 ; 0x800140 <__data_end+0x2>
-   12c:    f0 90 41 01     lds r15, 0x0141 ; 0x800141 <__data_end+0x3>
-   130:    6c 19           sub r22, r12
-   132:    7d 09           sbc r23, r13
-   134:    8e 09           sbc r24, r14
-   136:    9f 09           sbc r25, r15
-   138:    0e 94 68 06     call    0xcd0   ; 0xcd0 <__floatunsisf>
-   13c:    6b 01           movw    r12, r22
-   13e:    7c 01           movw    r14, r24
-   140:    60 91 44 01     lds r22, 0x0144 ; 0x800144 <counter>
-   144:    70 91 45 01     lds r23, 0x0145 ; 0x800145 <counter+0x1>
-   148:    80 91 46 01     lds r24, 0x0146 ; 0x800146 <counter+0x2>
-   14c:    90 91 47 01     lds r25, 0x0147 ; 0x800147 <counter+0x3>
-   150:    0e 94 6a 06     call    0xcd4   ; 0xcd4 <__floatsisf>
-   154:    9b 01           movw    r18, r22
-   156:    ac 01           movw    r20, r24
-   158:    c7 01           movw    r24, r14
-   15a:    b6 01           movw    r22, r12
-   15c:    0e 94 c7 05     call    0xb8e   ; 0xb8e <__divsf3>
-   160:    ab 01           movw    r20, r22
-   162:    bc 01           movw    r22, r24
-   164:    22 e0           ldi r18, 0x02   ; 2
-   166:    30 e0           ldi r19, 0x00   ; 0
-   168:    88 e4           ldi r24, 0x48   ; 72
-   16a:    91 e0           ldi r25, 0x01   ; 1
-   16c:    0e 94 a9 04     call    0x952   ; 0x952 <_ZN5Print5printEdi>
-   170:    60 e0           ldi r22, 0x00   ; 0
-   172:    71 e0           ldi r23, 0x01   ; 1
-   174:    88 e4           ldi r24, 0x48   ; 72
-   176:    91 e0           ldi r25, 0x01   ; 1
-   178:    0e 94 0b 03     call    0x616   ; 0x616 <_ZN5Print7printlnEPKc>
-   17c:    60 91 42 01     lds r22, 0x0142 ; 0x800142 <sum>
-   180:    70 91 43 01     lds r23, 0x0143 ; 0x800143 <sum+0x1>
-   184:    4a e0           ldi r20, 0x0A   ; 10
-   186:    50 e0           ldi r21, 0x00   ; 0
-   188:    88 e4           ldi r24, 0x48   ; 72
-   18a:    91 e0           ldi r25, 0x01   ; 1
-   18c:    0e 94 b0 03     call    0x760   ; 0x760 <_ZN5Print7printlnEii>

 // All this is just counter++
2   190:    80 91 44 01     lds r24, 0x0144 ; 0x800144 <counter>
2   194:    90 91 45 01     lds r25, 0x0145 ; 0x800145 <counter+0x1>
2   198:    a0 91 46 01     lds r26, 0x0146 ; 0x800146 <counter+0x2>
2   19c:    b0 91 47 01     lds r27, 0x0147 ; 0x800147 <counter+0x3>
2   1a0:    01 96           adiw    r24, 0x01   ; 1
1   1a2:    a1 1d           adc r26, r1
1   1a4:    b1 1d           adc r27, r1
2   1a6:    80 93 44 01     sts 0x0144, r24 ; 0x800144 <counter>
2   1aa:    90 93 45 01     sts 0x0145, r25 ; 0x800145 <counter+0x1>
2   1ae:    a0 93 46 01     sts 0x0146, r26 ; 0x800146 <counter+0x2>
2   1b2:    b0 93 47 01     sts 0x0147, r27 ; 0x800147 <counter+0x3>
20 total 

 // Get the registers back and return
2   1b6:    ff 90           pop r15
2   1b8:    ef 90           pop r14
2   1ba:    df 90           pop r13
2   1bc:    cf 90           pop r12
4   1be:    08 95           ret
12 total
```

That's more than 10 instructions.  I make it 74 clocks to run one full iteration. (`counter++` alone is 20 clock cycles - double your estimation for the total...)

You have to remember two important things:

- AVR is a RISC CPU - that means that seemingly simple operations can take multiple instructions to perform.
- AVR is an 8-bit CPU - that means that working with any variables bigger than 8 bits in size require far more complex code, and you work with 32-bit variables (and floats, but that's outside the timing loop section of your code).

Comment: I am counting 72 clock cycles per iteration in your disassembly (20 for `counter++`). It looks like you compiled without `-flto`.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Quite possibly, yes. I use UECIDE which may not use the same compilation flags as Arduino if they decide to change things like that randomly - also probably not the same version of the compiler (I have lots of versions to choose from).

Comment: @EdgarBonet ADIW is two clocks not one I see, even though it only needs one read from the flash. I was counting flash reads as clocks. So yes, there's even more than at first it appears.

Comment: Indeed, the Arduino folks changed the compilation flags, [adding LTO in 1.6.10](https://blog.arduino.cc/2016/07/27/download-the-new-arduino-ide-1-6-10/).

Comment: @EdgarBonet I should add that to the arduino core in UECIDE then really. It's time to build a new version anyway I guess.  Any way - I have listed (and summed) the actual clock cycle values in the answer now.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Oh... and for a "RISC" system, the AVR sure has a lot of instructions...

Answer (score 0):

The loop function is called within the framework of the Arduino IDE. 
Beyond the code you write, also an interrupt check is done, which also cost time, and explains the difference.

The following function CAN be called after every loop call.
See Majenko's answer about the details.

```
/*
  SerialEvent occurs whenever a new data comes in the hardware serial RX. This
  routine is run between each time loop() runs, so using delay inside loop can
  delay response. Multiple bytes of data may be available.
*/
void serialEvent() {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    // get the new byte:
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    // add it to the inputString:
    inputString += inChar;
    // if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag so the main loop can
    // do something about it:
    if (inChar == '\n') {
      stringComplete = true;
    }
  }
}
```

See [SerialEvent](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SerialEvent) for more info.

However, as Kwasmich's comment says, you can easily circumvent this by performing your test inside a `while`  loop.

Comment: Does the interrupt loop check really take ~50 cycles?

Comment: Repeat your experiment by moving the loop code into a `while(1) {}` loop inside of `setup()`. That way you can eliminate the contribution of the arduino framework.

Comment: I'm trying to find the code.

Comment: `SerialEvent` is an optional function the user may implement in their sketch if they want. If they don't implement it then nothing gets called. It does, however, do a quick check to see if the function has been defined or not though, which takes a couple of clock cycles.

Comment: @Majenko ... thanks, I will update my answer, and upvote yours.